# LM2902N short circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am using the LM2902 as a voltage follower. I recently discovered one of the wires to the input pin of one of the op amps was crimped In a tight spot and bare wire was touching the ground intermittently.

This was discovered because anytime the sensor was hooked up to op-amp 3 of the IC, its measurements would drop to 0.so I had to troubleshoot and probe everything.

I probed the lm2902 and found that between the input pin of op-amp 3 and the ground pin, the resistance was about 20k ohms and between that same pin and VCC, it was about 30k. All the other input pins on the other op-amps didn't even register anything on the 2000K ohm setting.

My question is this, if the remaining 3 op-amps on the lm2902 IC show infinite resistance WRT to ground and VCC from the input pins, can I guess that the other 3 op-amps have a high chance of being functional?

Comment: An LM2902 costs about $0.50 (onesy-twosy). If you have the capability to re-work this part, just re-work it.

Comment: That is the issue, this is a prototype, I need to test today. Re-soldering the PCB at this point would take alot of time. It's much cheaper to make a new one and quicker, but I do not have the parts atm. I just need it to work for 3 days.

Comment: If it were me, I'd place an order for the replacement parts right now, then go in the lab and start checking if it works well enough. And in the future, always order a couple spares of every part that costs less than $100 when building prototypes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input circuit of an LM2902 won't be damaged if it is shorted to ground.  Remove the short and the circuit should work properly.  If it doesn't then try using one of the other amplifiers.  If the opamp is damaged, then the input may have experienced a negative transient of over voltage condition.  The LM2902 has PNP transistors at the input (see diagram).  There is a small leakage current coming from the inputs.  Yes, if you measure a high impedance on the inputs there is a chance the inputs are not damaged.

[image]

Comment: I am editing my own response to correct typo: "transient OR over voltage condition"